# How to use SparkSession and StreamingContext together?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I'm trying to stream CSV files from a folder on my local machine (OSX). I'm using SparkSession and StreamingContext together like so:

```
val sc: SparkContext = createSparkContext(sparkContextName)
val sparkSess = SparkSession.builder().config(sc.getConf).getOrCreate()
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkSess.sparkContext, Seconds(time))

val csvSchema = new StructType().add("field_name",StringType)
val inputDF = sparkSess.readStream.format("org.apache.spark.csv").schema(csvSchema).csv("file:///Users/userName/Documents/Notes/MoreNotes/tmpFolder/")
```

If I run `ssc.start()` after this, I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No output operations registered, so nothing to execute
```

Instead if I try to start the `SparkSession` like this:

```
inputDF.writeStream.format("console").start()
```

I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
```

Clearly I'm not understanding how `SparkSession` and `StreamingContext` should work together. If I get rid of `SparkSession`, `StreamingContext` only has `textFileStream` on which I need to impose a CSV schema. Would appreciate any clarifications on how to get this working.

Answer (score 12):

You cannot have a spark session and spark context together. With the release of Spark 2.0.0 there is a new abstraction available to developers - the Spark Session - which can be instantiated and called upon just like the Spark Context that was previously available.

You can still access spark context from the spark session builder:

```
 val sparkSess = SparkSession.builder().appName("My App").getOrCreate()
 val sc = sparkSess.sparkContext
 val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(time))
```

One more thing that is causing your job to fail is you are performing the transformation and no action is called. Some action should be called in the end such as inputDF.show()

Comment: This example uses Spark Session and StreamingContext together - http://blog.antlypls.com/blog/2017/10/15/using-spark-sql-and-spark-streaming-together/

I have to use StreamingContext for compatibility with existing codebase.

Comment: Spark session and spark context doesn't go together. Any spark job can have one spark context and one spark streaming context.You can create a spark streaming context from either spark context or spark session.

I have edited the answer to create a spark streaming context.

Comment: And are the changes made to this StreamingContext reflected in SparkSession? For example, if I add a StreamingListener to this StreamingContext, and then use sparkSession.readStream to do everything, will that StreamingListener work? If this works, then how does the second argument Seconds(time) affect my structured streaming queries?