# How to register a StreamingListener with SparkSession?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a structured streaming application and I want to register a `StreamingListener` with it, how do I do that? I only seem to be able to register `StreamingQueryListener` via `sparkSession.streams.addListener()`.

I know how to add a `StreamingListener` into `StreamingContext`, but the problem seems to be in getting `StreamingContext`, if I create a `StreamingContext` from `SparkSession.sparkContext`, I don't think `StreamingListener` will work if I continue doing streaming from `SparkSession` instead of that `StreamingContext` that I created.

Here's my `StreamingListener` class:

```
import io.prometheus.client.{CollectorRegistry, Gauge}
import io.prometheus.client.exporter.PushGateway
import org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.{StreamingListener, StreamingListenerBatchCompleted}


class MicroBatchStatsListener(val pushGateway: PushGateway, jobName: String) extends StreamingListener {

  private val processingTimeGauge = Gauge.build()
    .name("processingTimeGauge")
    .help("Time it took to process this microbatch")
    .register(CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry)

  private val schedulingDelayGauge = Gauge.build()
    .name("schedulingDelayGauge")
    .help("Scheduling delay of this microbatch")
    .register(CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry)

  private val numRecordsGauge = Gauge.build()
    .name("numRecordsGauge")
    .help("Number of records received in this mircobatch")
    .register(CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry)

  override def onBatchCompleted(batchCompleted: StreamingListenerBatchCompleted): Unit = {
    val processingTime = if (batchCompleted.batchInfo.processingDelay.isDefined) {
      batchCompleted.batchInfo.processingDelay.get / 1000
    } else {
      0
    }

    val schedulingDelay = if (batchCompleted.batchInfo.schedulingDelay.isDefined) {
      batchCompleted.batchInfo.schedulingDelay.get / 1000
    } else {
      0
    }

    val numRecords = batchCompleted.batchInfo.numRecords

    processingTimeGauge.set(processingTime)
    schedulingDelayGauge.set(schedulingDelay)
    numRecordsGauge.set(numRecords)

    pushGateway.push(CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry, jobName)
  }
}
```

if I can't connect it to `SparkSession`, how do I do the same with `StreamingQueryListener`? I don't understand how to get these metrics from there:

1. Scheduling delay
2. Processing time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is impossible to register a `StreamingListener` for structured streaming, because `StreamingContext` is not available if you use structured streaming. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307317/how-to-use-sparksession-and-streamingcontext-together) method of getting `StreamingContext` does not work in this case, because it creates a separate `StreamingContext`, and if you register listeners with it, they won't work as you use structured streaming.

But all these metrics, can actually be computed with `StreamingQueryListener`, an example of what metrics it has is the following:

```
23/06/20 17:59:15 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Streaming query made progress: {
  "id" : "4005e0e1-de55-4e9e-a01f-2bd3eec3d77e",
  "runId" : "9d847913-72f8-4410-8b5f-0c69b798bc3c",
  "name" : null,
  "timestamp" : "2023-06-20T14:59:15.184Z",
  "batchId" : 3,
  "numInputRows" : 10,
  "inputRowsPerSecond" : 666.6666666666667,
  "processedRowsPerSecond" : 47.16981132075472,
  "durationMs" : {
    "addBatch" : 31,
    "getBatch" : 0,
    "getEndOffset" : 0,
    "queryPlanning" : 4,
    "setOffsetRange" : 0,
    "triggerExecution" : 212,
    "walCommit" : 112
  },
  "stateOperators" : [ ],
  "sources" : [ {
    "description" : "RateStreamV2[rowsPerSecond=10, rampUpTimeSeconds=0, numPartitions=default",
    "startOffset" : 2,
    "endOffset" : 3,
    "numInputRows" : 10,
    "inputRowsPerSecond" : 666.6666666666667,
    "processedRowsPerSecond" : 47.16981132075472
  } ],
  "sink" : {
    "description" : "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ConsoleSinkProvider@3d192c1a"
  }
}
```

We can add up all the values from `durationMs` and get the total processing time, for example.

Scheduling delays can also be computed from `durationMs` if you know the order of operations mentioned in that map. So, you'd have to add up all operations that happen before `triggerExecution` and you will get your scheduling delay.

Number of input records is also there.

All this info is available in the `StreamingQueryListener.QueryProgressEvent` class of `StreamingQueryListener`'s `onQueryProgress` method, which is triggered after every microbatch.

**UPDATE**: found a similar question and provided an answer for it here: [Structured Spark streaming metrics retrieval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58959668/structured-spark-streaming-metrics-retrieval/76536197#76536197)